# How add printer sdk POS system android app

Tags: android

I am fresher to android,I am developing android app for pos system.Already I have tested android demo app for POS(Point of Sale) system received from the manufacturer.I added its library to my android project.But printer is not working for my app,but the're app working properly.

This is the manufacturer printer Activtity :

```
        private class contentPrintThread extends Thread {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    super.run();
                    setName("Content Print Thread");
                    try {
                        ThermalPrinter.start(PrinterActivity.this);
                        ThermalPrinter.reset();
                        ThermalPrinter.setAlgin(ThermalPrinter.ALGIN_LEFT);
                        ThermalPrinter.setLeftIndent(leftDistance);
                        ThermalPrinter.setLineSpace(lineDistance);
                        if (wordFont == 4) {
                            ThermalPrinter.setFontSize(2);
                            ThermalPrinter.enlargeFontSize(2, 2);
                        } else if (wordFont == 3) {
                            ThermalPrinter.setFontSize(1);
                            ThermalPrinter.enlargeFontSize(2, 2);
                        } else if (wordFont == 2) {
                            ThermalPrinter.setFontSize(2);
                        } else if (wordFont == 1) {
                            ThermalPrinter.setFontSize(1);
                        }
                        ThermalPrinter.setGray(printGray);
                        ThermalPrinter.addString("test123");
                        ThermalPrinter.printString();
                        ThermalPrinter.clearString();
                        ThermalPrinter.walkPaper(100);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Result = e.toString();
                        if (Result.equals("com.telpo.tps550.api.printer.NoPaperException")) {
                            nopaper = true;
                        } else if (Result.equals("com.telpo.tps550.api.printer.OverHeatException")) {
                            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(OVERHEAT, 1, 0, null));
                        } else {
                            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(PRINTERR, 1, 0, null));
                        }
                    } finally {
                        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(CANCELPROMPT, 1, 0, null));
                        if (nopaper) {
                            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(NOPAPER, 1, 0, null));
                            nopaper = false;
                            return;
                        }
                        ThermalPrinter.stop(PrinterActivity.this);
                        Log.v(TAG, "The Print Progress End !!!");
                        if (isClose) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



private class MyHandler extends Handler {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (stop == true)
                    return;
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case NOPAPER:
                        noPaperDlg();
                        break;
                    case LOWBATTERY:
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PrinterActivity.this);
                        alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.operation_result);
                        alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.LowBattery));
                        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.dlg_ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            }
                        });
                        alertDialog.show();
                        break;
                    case PRINTVERSION:
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        if (msg.obj.equals("1")) {
                            textPrintVersion.setText(printVersion);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(PrinterActivity.this, R.string.operation_fail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        break;
                    case PRINTBARCODE:
                        new barcodePrintThread().start();
                        break;
                    case PRINTQRCODE:
                        new qrcodePrintThread().start();
                        break;
                    case PRINTPAPERWALK:
                        new paperWalkPrintThread().start();
                        break;
                    case PRINTCONTENT:
                        Log.e("task","in printcontent case");
                        new contentPrintThread().start();
                        break;
                    case MAKER:
                        new MakerThread().start();
                        break;
                    case PRINTPICTURE:
                        new printPicture().start();
                        break;
                    case CANCELPROMPT:
                        if (progressDialog != null && !PrinterActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            progressDialog = null;
                        }
                        break;
                    case EXECUTECOMMAND:
                        new executeCommand().start();
                        break;
                    case OVERHEAT:
                        AlertDialog.Builder overHeatDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PrinterActivity.this);
                        overHeatDialog.setTitle(R.string.operation_result);
                        overHeatDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.overTemp));
                        overHeatDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.dlg_ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            }
                        });
                        overHeatDialog.show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(PrinterActivity.this, "Print Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

***** This is the print button-

```
 buttonContentPrint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String exditText;
                exditText = editTextLeftDistance.getText().toString();
                if (exditText == null || exditText.length() < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(PrinterActivity.this, getString(R.string.left_margin) + getString(R.string.lengthNotEnougth), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                leftDistance = Integer.parseInt(exditText);
                exditText = editTextLineDistance.getText().toString();
                if (exditText == null || exditText.length() < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(PrinterActivity.this, getString(R.string.row_space) + getString(R.string.lengthNotEnougth), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                lineDistance = Integer.parseInt(exditText);
                printContent = editTextContent.getText().toString();
                exditText = editTextWordFont.getText().toString();
                if (exditText == null || exditText.length() < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(PrinterActivity.this, getString(R.string.font_size) + getString(R.string.lengthNotEnougth), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                wordFont = Integer.parseInt(exditText);
                exditText = editTextPrintGray.getText().toString();
                if (exditText == null || exditText.length() < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(PrinterActivity.this, getString(R.string.gray_level) + getString(R.string.lengthNotEnougth), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                printGray = Integer.parseInt(exditText);
                if (leftDistance > MAX_LEFT_DISTANCE) {
                    Toast.makeText(PrinterActivity.this, getString(R.string.outOfLeft), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                } else if (lineDistance > 255) {
                    Toast.makeText(PrinterActivity.this, getString(R.string.outOfLine), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                } else if (wordFont > 4 || wordFont < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(PrinterActivity.this, getString(R.string.outOfFont), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                } else if (printGray < 0 || printGray > 12) {
                    Toast.makeText(PrinterActivity.this, getString(R.string.outOfGray), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (printContent == null || printContent.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(PrinterActivity.this, getString(R.string.empty), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (LowBattery == true) {
                    handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(LOWBATTERY, 1, 0, null));
                } else {
                    if (!nopaper) {
                        setTitle("print character");
                        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PrinterActivity.this, getString(R.string.bl_dy), getString(R.string.printing_wait));
                        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(PRINTCONTENT, 1, 0, null));
//                      handler.sendMessage(handler.);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PrinterActivity.this, getString(R.string.ptintInit), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

            }
        })
```

;

1.can i add manufacturer app as module in my project ?

2.how add this codes in my app,and any other special ways to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On The SDK Manufacture Provided There is a libraries Folder , You Copy That Lib Folder To Your Project
Then After You Have Copied It You Go right click on the lib folder  ,i assume  you have copied it under app folder right click the libs folder , then add as library , it will be added, now you can include  the printer Activity : to your MainActivity ,, Create form where you ill input data and then purse that  Data to your btnprint

Answer (score -1):

Add all libraries in the demo app and also and the jniLibs as shown here [jniLibs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEH31.png)